# Application Needs Fiddler to Execute Properly on Some PCs

Tags: vb6, fiddler, winhttp

I have a VB6 application that only runs under certain conditions. When it fails (on the send statement below), it generates a

Run-time error '-2147012867 (80072efd)': A connection with the server could not be established

The funny thing is that it always runs when Fiddler is running. On some machines it runs whether or not Fiddler is running, but on other machines it will only run when Fiddler is running. Fiddler doesn't even have to be capturing traffic for it to run.

The request is to an https site.

The code looks like this:

```
Set xhr = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
xhr.open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sBody)
xhr.send sBody
```

I've read the Telerik article, [Help! Running Fiddler Fixes My App???](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-), but none of the suggested solutions seems to work.

Can anyone provide me with any insight on what might be wrong or how I can solve this?

Comment: What is the value of `bAsync`? Do you open the connection asynchronously?

Comment: No. It's set to false.

Comment: Did you try to use [WinHttp tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384084(v=vs.85).aspx) such as `WinHttpTraceCfg` in order to find where the issue may occur?

Comment: I hadn't tried a tracing tool. I tried to install WinHttpTraceCfg, but the installer didn't want me to do that on Windows 7. So, I used netsh winhttp. I ran both the success and failure cases and compared them. The failure case's trace displayed the following:

Comment: 18:22:10.495 ::sys-sender processing HttpSendHttpRequest completion (error-cdoe = WSAECONNREFUSED (0x274d), #bytes = 0, overlapped = 04837FA0)
18:22:10.495 ::sys-sender failed to a request; error = WSAECONNREFUSED (10061)
18:22:10.495 ::ERROR_WINHTTP_FROM_WIN32 mapped (WSAECONNREFUSED) 10061 to (ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT) 12029
18:22:10.495 ::sys-req shutting down; send-req encountered fatal error; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT (12029)
18:22:10.495 ::sys-req completing a send-request call (error = ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT (12029))

Comment: I looked up the above error code, but couldn't interpret why it applied in the failure case, but not the success case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check your `WinHttpSettings` registry key settings?

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Connections\WinHttpSettings

Default value (no proxy) is
[image]

I suppose that `Fiddler` modified this configuration in order to act as proxy.

If `Fiddler` is not running => no proxy => connection error.

In `WinHttpRequest`, if `setProxy` is not explicitly called => `HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_DEFAULT` => `HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PRECONFIG`

> HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PRECONFIG
>
> Indicates that the proxy settings should be obtained from the
>   registry.

Comment: Thanks! The reason you gave makes sense and explains why setting the proxy to 1 (xhr.setProxy 1) causes the application to work.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Proxy to HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_DIRECT solved the problem.

```
' Important Note: The setProxy setting of 1 corresponds to HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_DIRECT
' (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384059(v=vs.85).aspx)
' Without this, the app would only work on the dev machine when Telerik Fiddler was also
' running. Oddly, the app would run correctly on all other machines.

Set xhr = getRequestObject()
xhr.setProxy 1
xhr.open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sBody)
```

The Microsoft article cited above gives three values for the constants that the Proxy can be set to. I don't understand why the "Direct" setting worked, but it did.

Thanks to Jeandey and anyone else that looked at this.